# TypeORM single table inheritance use abstract classes between @Entity() and @ChildEntity()

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I would like to achieve the following single table inheritance with TypeORM:

```
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({column: {type: "varchar", name: "type"}})
export class BaseDevice {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({type: "uuid"})
  id: string;

  // other fields
}

abstract class MeasureableDevice extends BaseDevice {

  @Column()
  value: string;

  // other fields
}

@ChildEntity()
export class TemperatureSensor extends MeasureableDevice {

  @Column()
  position: string;

  // other fields
}
```

But when I run my application, I get the following error:

> (node:2574710) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'build' of undefined
> at /node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.js:526:83
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeEntityMetadataStep2 (/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.js:526:37)
> at /node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.js:81:74
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.js:81:25)
> at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (/node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.js:57:141)
> at Connection.buildMetadatas (/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:514:57)
> at Connection. (/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:127:30)
> at step (/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:2574710) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:2574710) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

When I remove the abstract class in between of `@Entity()` and `@ChildEntity()` classes and copy the `@Column()` fields of `abstract class MeasureableDevice` directly into `class TemperatureSensor` everything works. So it seems there is a problem with an abstract class in between those the annotated classes. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I found a solution for this. Simply adding `@ChildEntity()` annotation on `abstract class MeasureableDevice` did the trick. Just in case anybody else has the same question in future.